# how to draw circles on 2d plane in python

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, visualization

I've made a random walk simulation and I'd like it to output little circles at the coordinates of each step of the random walk and I'm not sure how to produce this visualization with python. I'd like it to look like this guy's output here http://www.manaware.net/scientific-programming/images/6002_883_45.jpg but I can't get in touch with him to see how he did that.
Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What package are you using to do the drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those plots look like they were made by [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). There is a [Python interface](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) for it too.

Answer (score 0):

look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html)

you could use PIL too if you really wanted.

Comment: cool, i figured it would involve matplotlib. I don't have a lot of experience with it - do you think you could point me towards the right toolkit?

Comment: toolkit probly not the right term. just wondering how i would go about building a little circle at a point in a coordinate plane in matplotlib

Comment: scatter plot demos: 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo.html
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo2.html

Comment: noice, thanks guys. Any ideas how I might draw little pie charts on the coordinate plane?

Comment: nevermind, I'll cross that bridge when I come to it and it might be easy to figure out.